# How can I add items after setting itemsource to ListView

Tags: wpf

I got exception : 
Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must add the items to your source-collection that is set to `ItemsSource`. After you have set the `ItemsSource`-property to a value, its no more possible to use the `Items`-property (besides you set `ItemsSource` newly to null). `Items` and `ItemsSource` exclude each other.

If you use `ItemsSource`, your source-collection must implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) so that it will inform the `ListView` about changes. If not, added items to it will not change the `ListView`. E.g. if you use `List<T>` as items-source, changes will not be forwarded.

There exist classes that do that for you such as [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

Comment: Do you use yourListView.Items.Add(newItem) or myObservableCollection.Add(newItem)

Comment: Thank you Now Its run comfortably

Comment: If it helped you, please mark the answer as accepted by checking the checkmark under the Points-display.